# Network status: What is "Difficulty"?

Tags: network

How to understand "[Difficulty](https://btc.com/stats/diff)" and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty is a measure of how difficult it is to find a hash below a given target.

The Bitcoin network has a global block difficulty. Valid blocks must have a hash below this target.